# How to save Google search to My contacts

Tags: contact-shortcut

Is it possible to, after searching for people or business on Google maps or on Google, to save the info to my contacts directly without typing in the info yourself? Unfortunately no longer have the option on Google maps to save contact, and I'm not sure I why Google removed that option. Maybe a different app would be an option, if anyone know one that would work? I have a Galaxy S5

Answer (score 1):

When you search for the business (or person), it will give you a phone number, if you click on that phone number, it will open the dialer.

Somewhere on the dialer there will be an option to add to contacts (on stock android it is at the top), click that, then click new contact, fill in the name, and you are done.

However, this doesn't include the name, or address, and I don't think there is an easy way of adding those (unless you have a business card with an nfc tag).

Comment: Disappointing, but I don't know of a better way.